# Как `super` из конструктора смог дотянуться до метода расширяемого класса? Метод же лежит в `A.prototype`. Или это специальное поведение?

Tags: javascript

```js
'use strict';
class A {
 f() {console.log('hello')}
}
class B extends A {
  constructor() {
   super();
   
   // super.f() - это вызов функции на родительском объекте
   console.log(B.__proto__ == A); // Родителем является А
   console.log(A.f === undefined); // Функции такой нет
   console.log(A.__proto__.f === undefined); // И в прототипе нет
   console.log(super.f == A.prototype.f); // Я знаю где она!
   console.log(A.__proto__ != A.prototype); // Но как же мы до неё добрались?
   super.f();
   
  }
  f() {console.log('bye')} // Если бы super применялся к this
  
}

new B();
```

Comment: учите наследование

Comment: А кто мешает ему дотянуться до `A.prototype`?

Comment: @PavelMayorov Отсутствие цепочки прототипов. Я дополнил пример.

Comment: Вы путаете класс и его прототип. Проверьте-ка `this.__proto__.__proto__ === A.prototype`

Comment: @PavelMayorov Вроде не путаю. `this` это создаваемый объект, понятно что у него есть `this.__proto__ == B.prototype` и далее `B.__proto__ == A.prototype`, но `super` же применяется не к `this`, а к объекту `B` - чтобы вызывать функцию на родительском объекте `A`.

Comment: С чего вы так решили?

Comment: @PavelMayorov С того что в создаваемом объекте `this` вообще нет никаких `super`. А если добавить то родительским объектом будет соответственно `B.prototype`. Короче наверно это просто особенность работы `super` - возможность вызывать методы не по цепочке прототипов.

Comment: @PavelMayorov А ещё я добавил одноимённый метод в `B` и он конечно не вызывается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном случае ошибка происходит из предположения, что

```
A.__proto__ === A.prototype
```

Однако это не так:

1. `A.prototype` - это просто свойство `A` хранящее объект, со свойствами описанными в теле класса.
2. `A.__proto__` - это свойство `A`, значение которое получается при помощи метода `Object.getPrototypeOf(A)`.

Данные два свойства никак не связаны между собой.

---

Чтобы разобраться что откуда берется, обратимся к [спецификации](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-runtime-semantics-classdefinitionevaluation)

#### ClassDefinitionEvaluation

В 6 пункте, в части g определяются значения

```
 protoParent = superClass.prototype;
 constructorParent = superclass;
```

Далее создается `proto`

```
 proto = Object.create(protoParent);
```

Далее создается `constructorInfo`

```
constructorInfo = DefineMethod(proto, constructorParent)
```

---

#### DefineMethod

- создается сама функция: `closure = FunctionCreate(...)`, прототипом устанавливается переданный `constructorParent`
- Вызывается `MakeMethod`: `MakeMethod(closure, proto)`.

---

#### MakeMethod

В этом методе для переданной функции устанавливается внутреннее поле `[[HomeObject]]`: `closure.[[HomeObject]] = proto`

#### Итого

В результате выполнения, в функции конструктора установлено внутренне поле [[HomeObject]], в котором хранится объект `proto` - прототип класса (Для примера кода из вопроса - `B.prototype`).

---

При вызове функции для нее [создается `EnvironmentRecord`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-newfunctionenvironment), которому в его поле [[HomeObject]] присваивается значение одноименного поля вызываемой функции.

---

#### Super

Теперь рассмотри работу ключевого слова [`super`, при обращении к свойству](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-super-keyword)

Как видно из алгоритма все сводится к вызову метода [MakeSuperPropertyReference](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-makesuperpropertyreference)

```
MakeSuperPropertyReference(actualThis, propertyName, strictFlag)
```

---

#### MakeSuperPropertyReference

В этом [методе](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-makesuperpropertyreference) у текущего EnvironmentRecord вызывается метод [`GetSuperBase`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-getsuperbase)

---

#### GetSuperBase

В этом методе берется значение `envRec.[[HomeObject]]`, как указано выше, в нем хранится прототип текущего объекта.

```
home = envRec.[[HomeObject]];
```

Возвращает метод результат выражения

```
home.[[GetPrototypeOf]]()
```

Что для нашего случая является значением `protoParent`.

---

### Общий итог:

обращение к `super` сводится к следующему:

```
super.identifier
```

это

```
proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(this); // B.prototype

parentProto = Object.getPrototypeOf(proto); // A.prototype

parentProto.identifier
```

Comment: То есть это баг самого языка?

Comment: @ValeraRybakoff, в смысле баг? Работает именно так, как описано в спецификации - никакого бага нет.

Comment: Вы правильно написали что `A.prototype` и `A.__proto__` это разные объекты. Но как `super.f();` из конструктора смог дотянуться до метода расширяемого класса? Нету цепочки прототипов. Метод же находится в `A.prototype`.

Comment: @ValeraRybakoff, вторая часть моего ответа как раз об этом.

Comment: 1. Вторая часть вашего ответа про создаваемый объект `this` который тут вообще ни при чём. 2. Далее вы приводите спецификацию что "ищется в прототипе текущего объекта" то есть в `A`, но в `A` нет метода `f` потому что он находится в `A.prototype` к которому не ведёт цепочка прототипов.

Comment: @ValeraRybakoff _"ищется в прототипе текущего объекта" то есть в A_ - нет, не в `A`, а в `A.prototype`. Вторая часть как раз и говорит, почему. Что ты понимаешь говоря "цепочка прототипов"? Очевидно, вся проблема в том, что ты неправильно трактуешь этот термин.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107431/discussion-between-grundy-and-valera-rybakoff).

Comment: Э-э-э, в конце у вас написано как будто `super.identifier` смотрит на прототип `this`. А оно смотрит на `[[HomeObject]]`, которое от `this` не зависит...

Comment: @PavelMayorov, ага, это просто чтобы показать откуда это proto берется, потому что по идее оно как бы сразу есть и первая строчка не нужна вообще

Comment: @PavelMayorov, могу ее убрать и заменить вторую на `parentProto = Object.getPrototypeOf(B.prototype)` - так лучше будет?

Comment: @Grundy Всё, до меня дошло. Конструктору устанавливается `[[HomeObject]]` в `B.prototype` и `super` его использует чтобы найти родителя `A.prototype` по цепочке прототипов. Спасибо. 

Answer (score 0):

Говоря простым языком: используя `extends` вы **должны** вызывать `super()` чтобы унаследовать свойства и методы родителя, если этого не сделать, то при первом обращении к `this` у Вас будет ошибка.

Поэтому ничего удивительного в том, что есть доступ к функции `f`.

[Вот](https://webdevblog.ru/chto-takoe-super-v-javascript/) интересная статейка с подробными примерами

Comment: 1. `super` не для того чтобы наследовать свойства и методы родителя. 2. И без обращения к `this` тоже будет ошибка если не вызвать `super();`. 3. Не понятно как `super` добирается до метода расширяемого класса из конструктора без цепочки прототипов.